# How to set themes, styles, colors etc. in a Xamarin, Android project so they won't be affected by Dark/Light mode?

Tags: xamarin, colors, properties, android-dark-theme, android-darkmode

My theme/color settings...

App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="PageBackgroundColor">#1F1F1F</Color>
        <Style TargetType="Entry">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Fill" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Whitesmoke" />
            <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TimePicker">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Picker">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
            <Setter Property="TitleColor" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
```

styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">  
    <item name="colorAccent">#ff0000</item>    
  </style>
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme">@style/MyTimePickerDialogStyle</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MyTimePickerDialogStyle" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#000000</item>
  </style>     
</resources>
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage ...
             BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}"
             ...>
    ...
    <Button ... TextColor="#F5F5F5" BackgroundColor="#007F00" ... />
    ...
    <Label ... BackgroundColor="#F5F5F5" ... />
```

My App is meant to be on a dark background regardless of the selected Dark/Light mode. Dark/Light mode should not affect any colours.
No colour problems with Light mode on Android 10.
With Dark mode:

- The button Green (#008000) becomes lime, which renders the white text colour unreadable, so I had to change the Button BackgroundColor property from Green (#008000) to #007F00, which surprisingly works fine although the difference between the two colours is minimal
- The label WhiteSmoke (#F5F5F5) becomes dark
- If I change the `<Setter Property="TextColor" Value="WhiteSmoke" />` to `<Setter Property="BackgroundColorColor" Value="WhiteSmoke" />`, the change will be applied only for light theme
- No problems with buttons that have BackgroundColor set to Red (#FF0000)

Why on Earth the Dark mode is affecting only certain colours? I guess there are some settings that can override the Dark mode. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Is there a way to deactivate Dark mode?
How to set themes, styles, colors etc. so they won't be affected by Dark/Light mode?

EDIT2: Screenshots...

Light mode:

[image: White mode]

Dark mode:

[image: Dark mode]

EDIT3: It affects images, too.

I tried with two almost identical images with the only difference a red & green background. The rest of the background is trasparent. The word 'swipe' and the arrow are of #F5F5F5 colour, while the circle around the 'A' is #FFFFFF. The images are fresh from Photoshop:

[image: swipe_colours]

[image: swipe_white]

Screenshots while on White / Dark mode:

[image: White_mode] ___ [image: White_mode]

As you can see the Dark mode affects only one of the two images similarly to the hex colors I mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

According to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes#set-the-current-user-theme), you can [Set the current user theme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes#set-the-current-user-theme):

> The theme used by the application can be set with the
> Application.UserAppTheme property, which is of type OSAppTheme,
> regardless of which system theme is currently operational:

```
Application.Current.UserAppTheme = OSAppTheme.Dark;
```

You can also set same color [under light/dark mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes#appthemebinding-markup-extension):

```
<Label Text="This text is green in light mode, and green in dark mode."
               TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=Green, Dark=Green}" />
```

Comment: Tried both Application.Current.UserAppTheme = OSAppTheme.Dark; & Application.Current.UserAppTheme = OSAppTheme.Light; , put the line in App.xaml.cs right after InitializeComponent(); with no effect. Also tried BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#F5F5F5, Dark=#F5F5F5}" on label, but the Dark mode would still make the label background dark.

Comment: Are you sure the label's background turns dark instead of other view's background color? Can you please add some screenshot to make it clear?

Comment: Screenshots added.

Comment: Does you app restart after change to dark mode? Why the delete button with red background does not has any change between light and dark mode?

Comment: The four 'Blah blah' at the bottom are CollectionView Items added dynamically by the 'ADD' button. Switching to dark/light mode would empty the CollectionView. This is the starting (Main) page of my app. When on another page, switching to dark/light mode would result in a redirect to the Main page, so I guess the app restarts right after switching. The app is not heavy so it does it instantly.

Comment: No button background color should change when switching dark/light mode as you can find above in the description of the problem. If I change all the buttons & labels backgrounds to red, they won't be affected after switching between dark/light, which is the wanted behaviour. The question is why it affects only certain colors?

Comment: You mean the problem only happens when you set color like `#F5F5F5`? It's fine if you set color like `Green`?

Comment: No, it's the same if you set color to #008000 or if you set color to Green. Both will become lime in dark mode.
#008000 == Green
But #007F00 would not be affected when switching dark/light mode. #007F00 and #008000 are almost the same colour.

Comment: Well, that's quite strange as hex color should be same. Will test and update you if I find anything.

Comment: I added another example. Check under EDIT3, please. Thank you.

Comment: OK, will look into that.